Is there a possibility to check if a library with a concrete name was loaded by system.loadLibrary in Java?
For example I have a library named "test1112" and loaded by code system.loadLibrary("test1112"). How can I check if it is loaded in a process?
I founded some answers here, for example How do I get a list of JNI libraries which are loaded?
But I`m not sure if it can help and also one of the answerers told that its impossible. Please help
